# Can a recursive sequence converge to a repulsive fixed point?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, fixed-points

Let's consider a recursive sequence defined as $U_{n+1}=f(U_n)$.
We already know that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(U_n)}$ converges, it'll converge to a fixed point of $f(x)$.

I just wonder if it's possible for it to converges to a repulsive fixed point $a$ of $f$

$|f'(a)|>1$

Is it possible, or STRICTLY IMPOSSIBLE for any recursive sequence associated with $f$ to converge to a repulsive fixed point of $f$?
Is there a theorem that forbids or allow it or not?

Comment: Consider the case where $u_0=a$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe's implication is correct, but I guess the OP wishes to use $U_{n+1}=f(U_n)$ to estimate $a$ whose exact value is unknown.

Comment: Well that's the def of a fixed point, but if $x_0≠a$ then it can't?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz and that's not what I'm aiming to do. I'm trying to demonstrate that a certain limit can't converge to a certain value

Comment: It also can happen that $u_k = a$ for an integer $k$, even if $u_0 \neq a$. But, you can prove that this is the only possibility : if the recursive sequence converges to $a$, then it is eventually constant.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I guess the OP is "lost in translation". In French for example, we say "suite récurrente" for "recursive sequence" (which does not mean recurrent in the dynamical sense).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Fine. Actually "recursive sequence" bothers me too - it's the definition of the sequence that's recursive. (If a recursive sequence is one that has a recursive definition then every sequence is recurrent. If it's a sequence that _has been given_ a recursive definition that's not a property of the sequence, for that matter not a "mathematical" property...)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, this can happen if the sequence $(U_n)$ is eventually constant. That's the only possible way:

> > Suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable, $f(a)=a$, $|f'(a)|>1$, $U_{n+1}=f(U_n)$ and $U_n\to a$. Then $(U_n)$ is eventually constant.

Proof: Note first that if there exists $k$ with $U_{k+1}=U_k$ then $U_n$ is eventually constant.

Wlog $f$ is real-valued; now wlog $f'(a)>1$. Since $f'$ is continuous, there exist $\lambda>1$ and $\delta>0$ such that $f'(x)>\lambda$ for every $x\in I=(a-\delta, a+\delta)$.

Now if $x,y\in I$ and $x<y$ then $$f(y)-f(x)\ge\lambda(y-x).$$So there exists $N$ such that $$|U_{n+2}-U_{n+1}|\ge\lambda|U_{n+1}-U_n|\quad(n>N).$$Hence if the sequence is not eventually constant then $|U_{n+1}-U_n|\to\infty$, $(U_n)$ does not converge.